# Poppet not sitting correctly in liquid post.

Tags: kegging, keg, corny-keg

I'm having some real trouble getting the poppet to sit correctly in the liquid post of my keg.  Below is an image with the poppet in:

[image]

Notice that there is a sizable gap between the poppet o-ring and the post itself.  I'm using a universal poppet, but it doesn't seem to be tall enough.  Below is a picture of what the connection looks like underneath the post (sorry it's a bit blurry):

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem?  Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a dip tube + o-ring there on top of the threads of the post? I can't quite make one out in the blurriness.

But even the height of a dip-tube lip + oring might not be enough to bridge that gap, which appears to be substantial. If not, perhaps the spring on the universal poppet is simply cut too short, and needs to be replaced.

I would not try to introduce a shim to bridge the gap, but instead replace the univeral poppet.

Comment: The dip tube is inside of the threading, with an o-ring underneath the lip of the dip tube.  This seems different than other kegs that i've seen, as there is nothing protruding out above the threading.  The poppet that I am using is brand new, so I'm not sure buying a new one would do me any good (I didn't cut it either).

Comment: I don't understand.  Is it (from top to bottom): removable threaded section with dip tube extension, oring, keg top?  That's … a/ something I've never heard of before and b/ totally ridiculous.